# java lang string cannot be cast to java lang double

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm trying to create music player using react native track player

but still there are many issues and one of them is

```
java lang string cannot be cast to java lang double
```

,
is it the package wrong or the implementation is wrong?

also i tried to apk release on real device , the music is not started.

are there any other solution or packages for music players in react native are better than this package or the error with the way i did it ?!!!!

the full code is down:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import TrackPlayer, {
    Event,
    useTrackPlayerEvents,
    usePlaybackState,
    TrackPlayerEvents,
    STATE_PLAYING,
    useProgress
} from 'react-native-track-player';




export const SongScreen = ({route}) => {
    const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const [songindex, setsongindex] = useState(0);
    const songslider = useRef(null);
    const isPlayer = useRef(false);
    const playpauseplayer = usePlaybackState();
    const isPlaying = useRef('playing');
    const progress = useProgress();

    useEffect(() => {
        scrollX.addListener(({ value }) => {
            const index = Math.round(value / width)
            setsongindex(index);
            TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.PlaybackTrackChanged, (e) => {
                console.log(e)
            }),
                TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
                    console.log("player ready");
                    await TrackPlayer.reset();
                    await TrackPlayer.add(songs);
                    isPlayer.current = true;
                    TrackPlayer.play();
                    if (isPlayer.current == true) {
                        TrackPlayer.skip(songs[songindex].id);
                        console.log("the track changed, id :", songindex);

                    }
                })
        })
        return () => { scrollX.removeAllListeners(); }
    },
        [songindex]);
        const formatTime = secs => {
            let minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
            let seconds = Math.ceil(secs - minutes * 60);
        
            if (seconds < 10) {
              seconds = `0${seconds}`;
            }
        
            return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
          };

    const changeicon = () => {
        switch (isPlaying.current) {
            case 'playing':
                return <Ionicons name="pause" size={30} />

            case 'paused':
                return <Ionicons name="play" size={30} />

            default:
                return <ActivityIndicator size={35} />
        }
    }
    const playpause = () => {
        if (playpauseplayer === 2 ) {
            TrackPlayer.play();
            console.log('track is playing');
            isPlaying.current = 'playing';
        }
        else if (playpauseplayer === 3 ) {
            TrackPlayer.pause();
            console.log('track is paused');
            isPlaying.current = 'paused';

        }
    }
    const skiptonext = () => {
        TrackPlayer.stop();
        songslider.current.scrollToOffset({
            offset: (songindex + 1) * width
        });
    }
    const skiptoback = () => {
        TrackPlayer.stop();
        songslider.current.scrollToOffset({
            offset: (songindex - 1) * width,
        });
    }
    const handlechange=(value)=>{
        TrackPlayer.seekTo(value)
    }

    const renderSongs = ({ index, item }) => {
        return (
            <Animated.View style={{ width: width, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 40 }}>
                <Image source={{ uri: item.artwork }} key={index} style={{ width: 300, height: 300, borderRadius: 10, }} />
            </Animated.View>

        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#777777" }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 11, justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View style={{ width: width }}>
                    <Animated.FlatList
                        ref={songslider}
                        data={songs}
                        renderItem={renderSongs}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                        horizontal
                        pagingEnabled
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                        scrollEventThrottle={16}
                        onScroll={Animated.event(
                            [{
                                nativeEvent: {
                                    contentOffset: { x: scrollX }
                                }
                            }],
                            { useNativeDriver: true },
                        )}


                    />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", alignItems: "center", marginTop: 60 }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 25, }}>{songs[songindex].title}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginTop: 4 }}>Descrption</Text>
                    <Slider
                        style={{ width: "90%", height: 30, marginTop: 10, flexDirection: "row" }}
                        value={progress.position}
                        minimumValue={0} 
                        maximumValue={progress.duration}
                         thumbTintColor='#ffd369' 
                         minimumTrackTintColor='#ffd369' 
                         maximumTrackTintColor='#FFF' 
                         onSlidingComplete={handlechange} />
                    <View style={{ width: "90%", flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                        <Text>
                            {formatTime(progress.position)}
                        </Text>
                        <Text>
                            {formatTime(progress.duration)}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ width: "60%", flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: "space-between", marginTop: 20 }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={skiptoback}>
                            <Ionicons name="play-skip-back" size={30} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => playpause()}>
                            {changeicon()}
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={skiptonext}>
                            <Ionicons name="play-skip-forward" size={30} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
   
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be weird, but maybe it is related to this piece of code:

```js
const formatTime = secs => {
  let minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  let seconds = Math.ceil(secs - minutes * 60);
        
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`; // seconds used to be a number, but is being made a string now. Totally valid in javascript, not so in Java
  }
        
  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};
```

So maybe change this to:

```js
const formatTime = secs => {
  let minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  let seconds = Math.ceil(secs - minutes * 60);
        
  return seconds < 10
    ? `${minutes}:0${seconds}`
    : `${minutes}:${seconds}`
};
```

And check whether the issue is resolved.

Comment: it's giving me possible unhandled promise rejection